# Почему Lambda выражения ведут себя по разному для Kotlin и Java классов?

Tags: kotlin

Почему для класса `java.lang.Thread` можно использовать Lambda, а для `MyThread` нельзя ?

```
interface MyRunnable{
    fun run()
}

class MyThread(runnable : MyRunnable){    
}

fun test(){
    Thread({})     // All Alright

    MyThread({})   //Exception. Type mismatch <<-- Why ?
}
```

Ссылка чтобы проверить этот пример:
https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/tbs79qfkh50psp7r3qrdrinrmt/sfkpjq1bjvg4r6d5rmnu6mp4a8

Comment: Кажется, [так задумано](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions): "Also note that this feature works only for Java interop; since Kotlin has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore unsupported."

Answer (score 1):

Потому что @FunctionalInterface работают только для Java-интерфейсов, для Kotlin они не нужны - в Kotlin есть встроенные функциональные типы, т.е. вы можете сразу писать:

```
class MyThread(runnable : () -> Unit)
```

И не создавать для этого отдельный интерфейс.